# Se puede redimensionar una imagen en tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas

Tengo una pregunta existe un manera viable de redimenzionar una imagen sin usar ninguna libreria externa ,solo tkinter si tener que utilizar librerias externas(Pillow,opencv,...)
ya intente usar el metodo `.zoom`y`.subsample` en tkinter.

```py
Perro=PhotoImage(file="Mi_perro.png")
Perro.zoom(2)
```

pero la imagen se agranda demasiado y no es 100% redimensionable,por ejemplo que pueda hacer algo como.

```
Perro.resize_image(100,34)
```

y la imagen se distorsione con el fin de llegar a ese tamaño.

alguien podria decirme como hacerlo de una manera viable **sin usar librerias externas**

muchas gracias a los que respondan :)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba combinando con .zoom(x int , y int) (aumentar) y .subsample(x int , y int) (reducir).

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
imagen = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'Mi_perro.png')
imagen = imagen.subsample(10)
tk.Label(root, image = imagen).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: nooooo,no admite un valor zoom(0.5) o algo asi,ni tampoco puedo saber el tamaño que quiero exactamente tengo que estar adivinando. :'(